# java gwt flowpanel always new line

Tags: java, gwt, flowpanel

I'm trying to use a flowpanel in java gwt but when I add different widgets, the panel adds every widget in a new line, here is how I set the flowPanel

```
 public class Test extends Composite {
   public abstract class SomeWidget<T> extends Composite {
      ...
   }

   public class SomeStringWidget extends SomeWidget<String> {
      ...
   }


   public void setWidget() {
     FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
     fp.setWidth("100%");
     fp.add(new SomeStringWidget());
     fp.add(new SomeStringWidget());
     ...
   }
 }
```

Why is every Widget set in a new line and not, as the flowpanel should, add the widgets in a line till there is no more space and then add them in a new line??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing same issue and assigned style to FlowPanel widget to align widgets in a line. This will solve your problem.

```
FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
fp.setStyleName("flowPanel_inline");
```

style.css

```
.flowPanel_inline
{
    display:inline;
}
```

Also you have to set this same style in added elements also.

Comment: you have to set this styles in all elements which you are going to add in it. I don't know what type widget you added. but it's required.

Comment: try with different styles like  `float: left` or  `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`  as @Sam suggest. because chrome may have some issue with it.

Comment: you don't have to set this style at fp... only in the inne widgets.

Answer (score 7):

Flow Panel generates a DIV-Element with the Style GWT-FlowPanel. If you want that you inner Widgets are inline make the CSS of the inner Widgets with the following CSS:

```
.SomeStringWidget {
   display: inline;
}
```

or

```
.SomeStringWidget {
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

or

```
.SomeStringWidget {
   float: left;
}
```

And in your widget set the CSS Class .SomeStringWidget in the constuctor.

```
public SomeStringWidget {
    this.setStyleName("SomeStringWidget");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SomeStringWidget is a Label, then it will always be a new line. If you don't want the newline, use InlineLabel.